# UIImagePickerController not saving image to UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

So I have looked around and tried a few different things and I still can't seem to figure out why the image is not being saved to the UIImageView. I have checked and the View Controller conforms to all protocols as necessary and I have set the Image Picker delegate to self. here is the code for handling the image that is chosen. Everything else works just no image is sent to the Image View after it is selected.

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
recipeImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dismissing imagePicker first like this

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) 
{
picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
recipeImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}
```

Comment: That worked! I must have forgotten to set the delegate earlier when I had it that way originally and then tried other solutions and forgot to put it back! I will accept the answer when SO lets me